# i want to use GdipDrawString api in vc++ but i do'nt know which header file should be include

Tags: c++

i want to use GdipDrawString api in vc++ but i do'nt know  which header file should be include

Answer (score 0):

After searching MSDN i found that the function which you are using is part of GDI+ flat API. According to MSDN you have to use header file Gdiplusflat.h and dll Gdiplus.dll.

Check out the following link for more details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533969(v=VS.85).aspx